# Searching Access Database by last name

Tags: c#, search, webforms

I cannot get my search button to take me to the gridview I created on another web form. Below is the Code I am using, I have tried the try/catch code and that gave me errors.

Here the code I have, the only issues with it is when I type in the last name, and hit search, the page does nothing. It will not go to the next page and display on gridview.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=PayrollSystem_DB.mdb");
con.Open();
string strqrySearch = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel where LastName = @LastName";
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(strqrySearch, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("strqrySearch", txtSearchName.Text.Trim());
OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

string strFname = "";
string strPayrate = "";
string strStartdate = "";
string strEnddate = "";
while (dr.Read())
{
    strFname = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
    strPayrate = dr["PayRate"].ToString();
    strStartdate = dr["StartDate"].ToString();
    strEnddate = dr["EndDate"].ToString();
    Response.Redirect("frmViewPersonnel.aspx");
}

dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: It is because you have put Response.Redirect in the dr.Read() loop and there is no record coming in the DataReader. If you still want that you should redirect it to the next page then don't write response.redirect in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("strqrySearch", txtSearchName.Text.Trim());
```

by this line.

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtSearchName.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: In OleDB, the name of the parameter doesn't matter.  It goes by index.

Comment: Would I redirect using the postback url? I beleive I am required not to use the postback url..so Do I move the rediredct to another location. Thank you sohail.hussain.dyn, why would I put @lastname